# Fallo al intentar apt-get update o apt-get install de cualquier paquete

Tags: ubuntu, update, virtualbox

me llevo pegando bastante con esto y no doy con la clave:
Me acabo de instalar una máquina virtual VM Virtual Box con Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS y desde el primer momento no me deja hacer un apt-get update ni instalar ningún paquete. Los errores son:
-Cuando ejecuto "apt-get update" ->
Descargados 9.028 kB en 16s (549 kB/s)
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
E: Fallo al obtener http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64  Falló la conexión [IP: xxx]
E: Fallo al obtener http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64  Falló la conexión [IP: xxx]
E: Fallo al obtener http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64  Falló la conexión [IP: xxx]
E: Fallo al obtener http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/main/cnf/Commands-amd64  Falló la conexión [IP: xxx]
E: No se han podido descargar algunos archivos de índice, se han omitido, o se han utilizado unos antiguos en su lugar.

-CUando ejecuto, por ejemplo, "apt-get install git" ->
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
git : Depende: liberror-perl pero no es instalable
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.

Las soluciones que he visto han sido cambiar el archivo sources.list, he intentado los cambios propuestos pero me sigue dando los mismos errores

Comment: ¿Tienes conectividad a internet? ¿Puedes abrir cualquier página?

Comment: Sí, de hecho este hilo lo he abierto desde la propia máquina para ver que todo funcionase bien. Ahora mismo estoy por cable en mi empresa, no sé si podría tener algo que ver pero tanto desde máquina como fuera de ella puedo acceder a cualquier página

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: tu problema esta relacionada al manejo de aplicaciones en el sistema operativo o configuración de tu red, y no a algo relacionado a los objetivos del sitio (Desarrollo y programación).